# CakePHP Select count thrown off by HAVING and AS

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, max, having

I'm developing a page that contains buckets which are pretty much containers for users we have in our system. Each bucket uses different conditions and fields to get different kinds of users.

As of now the buckets conditions,fields and everything else are stored in a massive array. We were hoping this would make adding buckets relatively simple but now we also get a count of customers in each bucket which has led us to a problem with our latest bucket (declined)

**Here's the error thats getting returned after we call getCount().**

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'most_recent' in 'having clause'
```

**Now I realize that were getting this error because were not including the fields array but including the fields breaks all the other buckets. We've tried using cakes $this->model->find('count',) but this was unsuccessful as well.**

So I'm unsure how to get the count accurately without including fields into the count.

**Declined Bucket**

```
'Declined' => array(
                'color' => '#33CC33',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Program.deal_status' => 'declined',
                    "Customer.sales_associate {CONDITION}",
                    "Program.date_submitted > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 60 DAY)",
                    'Customer.store {STORE_CONDITION}',
                ),
                'joins' => array(
                    array(
                        'table' => 'programs',
                        'alias' => 'Program',
                        'type' => 'LEFT',
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'Program.customer_id = Customer.customer_id'
                        )
                    ),
                    array(
                        'table' => 'activities',
                        'alias' => 'Activity',
                        'type' => 'LEFT',
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'Activity.customer_id = Customer.customer_id',
                        )
                    ),
                    array(
                        'table' => 'customer_interactions',
                        'alias' => 'CustomerInteraction',
                        'type' => 'LEFT',
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'CustomerInteraction.customer_id = Customer.customer_id'
                        )
                    )
                ),
                'order' => array(
                    'Program.date_submitted DESC',
                ),
                'group' => array(
                    'Activity.customer_id HAVING most_recent NOT BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) and DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)',
                ),
                'fields' => array(
                    'customer_id' => 'DISTINCT Customer.customer_id',
                    'Customer' => "CONCAT_WS(' ', CustomerPersonalInformation.first_name, CustomerPersonalInformation.last_name) AS full_name",
                    'Email' => 'CustomerContactInformation.email',
                    'Last Interaction' => 'CustomerInteraction.notes',
                    'Program Date' => 'Program.date_submitted',
                    'Underwriter notes' => 'Program.underwriters_notes',
                    'Last Activity Date' => 'Activity.date',
                    'hidden' => 'MAX(Activity.date) AS most_recent',
                )
            ),
```

**Get Count:**

```
public function getCount($department, $table, $employeeId = 'all',  $store = 'all'){


        $this->layout = 'blank';

        $bucket = $this->buckets[$department][$table];

        switch ($department) {
            case 'bdc':
                if ($employeeId === 'all'){
                    $storeConditionReplace = ($store === 'all') ? "IS NOT NULL" : " = '$store'";
                    $conditionReplace = "IS NOT NULL";
                    break;
                }
                $conditionReplace = " = '$employeeId'";
                break;
            case 'sales':
                if ($employeeId === 'all'){
                    $storeConditionReplace = ($store === 'all') ? "IS NOT NULL" : " = '$store'";
                    $conditionReplace = "IS NOT NULL";
                    break;
                }
                $conditionReplace = " = '$employeeId'";
                break;
        }

        foreach ($bucket['conditions'] as &$condition) {
            if(is_array($condition)){
                continue;
            }
            $condition = str_replace('{CONDITION}', $conditionReplace, $condition);
            if (isset($storeConditionReplace))
                $condition = str_replace('{STORE_CONDITION}', $storeConditionReplace, $condition);
            elseif (strpos($condition, '{STORE_CONDITION}') !== false)
                $condition = null;
        }
        $result = $this->Customer->find('count', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    $bucket['conditions'],

                ),
                'fields' => array(
                    'COUNT(DISTINCT Customer.customer_id)'
                ),  
                'group' => ((isset($bucket['group'])) ? $bucket['group'] : null),
                'order' => array(
                    $bucket['order'],
                ),
                'contain' => array(
                    'CustomerPersonalInformation',
                    'CustomerMarketingOption',
                    'CustomerContactInformation'
                ),
                'joins' => $bucket['joins']
            )
        );
        $this->set('count',$result);


    }
```

Comment: Kindly show the generated sql query.